# Perform Subquery in SSRS with Parameterized Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, reporting-services, parameters

Summary:
I have a query that I would like to parameterize for user specified tables and user specified dates in SSRS.  The query includes several CTE's.
How do I use the paramertized query as a CTE?

I have been able to paramertize the "selectedData" and it works like this:

```sql
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
Select @cmd = ' select  [id] 
      ,[theTime]
      ,[theDate]
      ,[KW]
      ,[airspeed_mph]
     , [avg_drive_speed]
     ,Lag([avg_drive_speed]) over (order by id) previousValue
From [tunnelData].[dbo].['  + @tunnel + ']
where [theDate]>=(' + @date + ' )'
exec (@cmd)
```

Now I want to add this as a CTE to reduce the data further in the query.  The following code was my attempt but I get an error from the Query Designer in SSRS "incorrect syntax near 'declare'"

```sql
-- First the Paramerized Table

WITH selectedData as (
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)

Select @cmd = ' select  [id] 
      ,[theTime]
      ,[theDate]
      ,[KW]
      ,[airspeed_mph]
      ,[avg_drive_speed]
     ,Lag([avg_drive_speed]) over (order by id) previousValue
From [tunnelData].[dbo].['  + @tunnel + ']
where [theDate]>=(' + @date + ' )'
exec (@cmd)  ),


-- Second Table to Reduce Data

lagData as (
    SELECT *,
        Lag([theTime]) over (order by id) previousTime
    from selectedData
    where [avg_drive_speed] >= 40 and previousValue < 40 OR [avg_drive_speed] < 40 and previousValue >= 40
    ) 

-- Last Select to Calculate Difference

Select *,
Case 
    when avg_drive_speed >= 40
    then 0 
    else datediff(SECOND, previousTime, [theTime]) 
end AS runTime

from lagData
order by [theDate] ASC, [theTime] ASC
```

I can run the CTE without the parameterization and it works:

```sql
With selectedData as (
    Select
       [id]
      ,[theTime]
      ,[theDate]
      ,[KW]
      ,[airspeed_mph]
      ,[avg_drive_speed]
      ,Lag([avg_drive_speed]) over (order by id) previousValue

      FROM [tunnelData].[dbo].[aus]                                             
      where [theDate]>='2019-08-07' and [theDate]<= '2019-08-07'
      ),

lagData as (
    SELECT *,
        Lag([theTime]) over (order by id) previousTime
    from selectedData
    where [avg_drive_speed] >= 40 and previousValue < 40 OR [avg_drive_speed] < 40 and previousValue >= 40
    ) 

Select *,
Case 
    when avg_drive_speed >= 40
    then 0 
    else datediff(SECOND, previousTime, [theTime]) 
end AS runTime

from lagData
order by [theDate] ASC, [theTime] ASC
```

Here are the results I get if I remove the paramertization (@tunnel / @date) and run the code immediately above this:

[Output Table Image from SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfJNc.png)

Comment: I m not sure If I understand your question correctly but I think below link wil give you more idea about parameters in SSRS. Let me know if this is what you are looking for   
1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017
2.https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5757/create-dynamic-ssrs-reports-using-a-query-as-an-input-parameter/

Comment: Thanks.  I have read through these before but I am still having some trouble.  Let me add some details to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you would place the entire query in the dynamic variable:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = '

    with 

        selectedData as (

            select     ....
            from       [tunnelData].[dbo].[' + @tunnel +']                                             
            where      [theDate] >= ''' + @date + '''

        ),

        lagData as (...) 

        select      ...
        from        lagData
        order by    [theDate] ASC, [theTime] ASC

';

exec (@cmd);
```

Fill in the ellipsis accordingly.

But be very careful.  Your code is very prone to sql injection via the @tunnel and @date variables.

Comment: Fantastic.  This works perfectly.  Thank You pwilcox.